# In what ways can abstract contracts or interfaces be used?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, interfaces, abstract

I'm currently learning solidity with an udemy course: https://www.udemy.com/course/blockchain-developer/ and the contents of it are also published here: https://ethereum-blockchain-developer.com/000-introduction/03-course-structure/

In on of the sections final implementation task, I'm having trouble understanding the solution. In summary, we have implemented a token based on the ERC20-contract. And based in this token we somehow want to implement a TokenSale contract that gets an allowance for spending tokens and offers the possibility to sell tokens to other addresses through a purchase function.

Now this is the contract for the Token itself:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract CoffeeToken is ERC20, AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    event CoffeePurchased(address indexed receiver, address indexed buyer);

    constructor() ERC20("CoffeeToken", "CFE") {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function buyOneCoffee() public {
        _burn(_msgSender(), 1);
        emit CoffeePurchased(_msgSender(), _msgSender());
    }

    function buyOneCoffeeFrom(address account) public {
        _spendAllowance(account, _msgSender(), 1);
        _burn(account, 1);
        emit CoffeePurchased(_msgSender(), account);
    }
}
```

and this is the solution for the token sale contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

abstract contract ERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint amount) external;
    function decimals() external view returns(uint);
}

contract TokenSale {
    uint tokenPriceInWei = 1 ether;

    ERC20 token;

    constructor(address _token) {
        token = ERC20(_token);
    }

    function purchase() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= tokenPriceInWei, "Not enough money sent");
        uint tokensToTransfer = msg.value / tokenPriceInWei;
        uint remainder = msg.value - tokensToTransfer * tokenPriceInWei;
        token.transfer(msg.sender, tokensToTransfer * 10 ** token.decimals());
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(remainder); //send the rest back

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, in the previous sections nothing was lectured about abstract contracts or interfaces and I'm having trouble understanding how these lines exactly work:

```
ERC20 token;

constructor(address _token) {
    token = ERC20(_token);
}
```

It reminds me of having a custom type of `ERC20` which the variable `token` becomes when calling this function in the constructor `token = ERC20(_token);`
But I have no clue how and why?

Can you please explain? Or give me any hints to reading material so that I can look it up. I haven't any explanations yet how this special case works behind the scenes.

Thanks!

Comment: You use abstract (or interface) to declare a contract's functions without providing the implementation. To use an ERC20 token from the TokenSale contract you don't need the implementation of the token, knowing the functions and its parameters should be enough.